# Request issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I am developing i small app that displays some JSON data
inside of a listview. To receive the data I am using a simple request.
And I am getting always the same issue:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

my code:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost/documents.json',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
    // do something with the data
   },
   type: 'GET'
});      
});
```

My JSON file is valid. I checked it with a JSON validator.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /` you may want to check the error line number as we cannot do it ...

Comment: Also if your json is valid json you shouldnt need to parse it

Comment: Getting the exception when? Did your `alert` come up? Did you  debug and test the value of  `data` in your callback? Also posting dead code (`cellPushed` is never used) shows that you didn't put enough work into crafting a good question. Last unrelated thing: `language="JavaScript"` is deprecated

Comment: You call a full URL (is it a cross-site request?) asking for plain text and then parse it as JSON, so I guess you're getting random output that jQuery tries to handle as JSONP. If you want JSON, why don't you simply ask for it and let jQuery do the job for you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I have updated my code where I simply ask for JSON but I am still getting that issue. My JSON file is valid. I have checked it.

Comment: I'm confused by your updated code. If it's a cross-site request and you expect JSONP then getting JSON back cannot work. You need that your server actually sends JSONP, not plain JSON. Details like resource extension and `format: 'json'` suggest it might not be the case. To sum up: 1) Do you really **need** JSONP instead of JSON? 2) Does your server send JSON or JSONP?

Comment: I do not need JSONP. JSON is enough. And yes, my server sends JSON

Comment: At the end of your code, I can see that you are closing the $.ajax() two times. Is it a typo? If not just remove one and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid JSON (no matter how mangled) cannot generate a JavaScript syntax error if you parse it with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or any decent dedicated parser (and that's what jQuery does). The same happens with all other standard data types (XML, HTML, plain text...). All symptoms suggest you're expecting JSONP but getting some other data type. The builtin browser network pane should reveal what you're getting exactly.

Whatever, if you only want JSON and nothing but JSON you should simplify your code as follows:

1. Omit protocol and host:

   ```
   url: 'http://localhost/documents.json',
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   url: '/documents.json',
   ```

   (Probably not required, but will help to void errors.)
2. Ask for the correct data type:

   ```
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   dataType: 'json',
   ```
3. Do not parse again what jQuery already parsed for you:

   ```
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   var json = data; // Yeah, nothing :)
   ```

This should be enough for local AJAX. If you really need a cross-site request (I asked twice and never got an answer) you have to tweak your server to either return the appropriate CORS headers **or** implement JSONP data type and change your client-side code accordingly because you'll no longer have JSON—because JSONP is not JSON!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your json is valid by using jsonlint.com or you can use jsonmate.com. These are very helpful to me when I'm debugging json.

Also - it would help to have a link to the full code. Use jsfiddle.net to put your code into - then link it to this post. This will help the community debug your code.

Comment: They typically don't need jsfiddle, they can run the code directly from the post.